# Circle reference (provider -> model -> provider)

Tags: vb.net, reference, geometry

i'm creating a new way to do the things in my project and i need some help in some point.
I have 3 projects in my solution:

Buusiness, Provider and Model.

The MODEL project, is the one that i have the classes just like the tables in database:
Ex:

```
public class Person
    property Id as integert?
    property Name as string
    property CPF as string
end class
```

the PROVIDER project, is the one that makes the communication with database:

```
public class PersonProvider
     public function ListPerson(filter as model.person) as list(of model.person)

     public sub insertPerson(byRef person as model.peson)

     public sub updatePerson(byRef person as model.peson)

     public sub deletePerson(byRef person as model.peson)
end class
```

and finally, i have the BUSINESS project, that's the project that exposes the CRUD methods to the website (the website must not have access to the PROVIDER, because we have business logic in the BUSINESS)

```
public class PersonBusiness
    public function ListPerson(filter as model.person) as list(of model.person)
           return (new provider.PersonProvider).listPerson(filter)
    end public

    public sub InsertPerson(byRef person as model.person)
           dim provider as new provider.PersonProvider()
           provider.insertPerson(person)
    end public

...

end class
```

But, i have come to a problem when i need some inner joins like this:

table CUSTOMER have an id_person, so in model.Customer i have a property IdPerson as integer?

but i want to have the properties Name and CPF that the model.Person have, read only property in the model.Customer, so i've made:

```
    Property IdPerson As Integer?
    Private _person As Pessoa
    Private ReadOnly Property Person As model.Person
        Get
            If IsNothing(_person) Then
                _person = New provider.PersonProvider.ListPerson(new model.Person with {.Id = Me.IdPerson})
            End If
            Return _person 
        End Get
    End Property

    ReadOnly Property Name As String
        Get
            Return Me.Person.Name
        End Get
    End Property

    ReadOnly Property CPF As String
        Get
            Return Me.Pessoa.CPF
        End Get
    End Property
```

and here comes the question... i found that i can't have reference like:

Website reference Model and Business

Provider reference Model

Business reference Model and Provider

but to do the readonly Properties the Model needs reference to Provider, and that causes a circle reference..visual studio doesn't allow me to do this...

any idea how to do this?

Sorry that my post become so long, i just wanted to make things clear.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accessing Model by Website and Business, you could add another class that references Provider and Person, and this new class will referenced by Website and Business (instead of Website and Business referencing Person directly).

Comment: hmm sorry but, i can't understand..
how that i populate an Person object in website to pass it to business if i don't have reference to the model?

Comment: The new class will be used to populate a Person instance, and the instance of the new class (and so the Person instance) can be passed to Business.